# Vertex array object not binding correctly in OpenGL 4.1

Tags: ios, macos, opengl, opengl-4

I'm in the process of porting some drawing code from OpenGLES 2.0 to OpenGL 4.0, and I'm running issues getting my vertex array object to bind.  When I run glValidateProgram I get this error: `Validation Failed: No vertex array object bound`

Here's the code I'm using for drawing:

```
void RendererRender(RendererRef* renderer) {

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    glUseProgram(program);

    glViewport(0, 0, renderer->viewportWidth, renderer->viewportHeight);
    glClearColor(0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    GLKMatrix4 projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakePerspective(M_PI/4.0, 1.0f, 0.1f, 10000.0f);

    GLKMatrix4 modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeLookAt(0,0,-10,
                                            0,0,0,
                                            0,1,0);

    glUniformMatrix4fv(modelViewMatrixUniformLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, modelViewMatrix.m);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(projectionMatrixUniformLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, projectionMatrix.m);

    glGetError();

    glBindVertexArray(triangleVAOId);
    if(!validateProgram(program)){
        NSLog(@"Error validating program");
        glGetError();
    }

    glPointSize(10.0f);
    glDrawElements(GL_POINTS, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, NULL);

}
```

So it seems as if the VAO should definitely be bound at this point.  The VAO is generated using the following code:

```
typedef struct {
    GLfloat position[3];
} Vertex;


GLuint buildVAO(int vertexCount, Vertex* vertexData, GLushort* indexData, BOOL hasTexture)
{

    GLuint vaoId;
    GLuint indexId;

    //generate the VAO & bind
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vaoId);
    glBindVertexArray(vaoId);

    GLuint positionBufferId;

    //generate the VBO & bind
    glGenBuffers(1, &positionBufferId);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBufferId);

    //populate the buffer data
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
                 vertexCount*sizeof(Vertex),
                 vertexData,
                 GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    //setup the attribute pointer to reference the vertex position attribute
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(kVertexPositionAttributeLocation);
    glVertexAttribPointer(kVertexPositionAttributeLocation,
                          kVertexSize,
                          kPositionVertexTypeEnum,
                          GL_FALSE,
                          sizeof(Vertex),
                          (void*)offsetof(Vertex, position));

    }

    //create & bind index information
    glGenBuffers(1, &indexId);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexId);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexCount*sizeof(GLushort), indexData, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    //restore default state
    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    return vaoId;
}
```

The other thing that I'm noticing is that the VAO id I get back from `glGenVertexArrays` is a large value, like 1606408096, where in the example I have working it's always something like 1 or 2.

This is all happening on the main thread.

Any idea what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out - it turns out it was because I was using the wrong version of `glGenVertexArray`.

I had this declaration earlier:

```
#define glGenVertexArrays glGenVertexArraysAPPLE
```

It turns out this is only necessary on OpenGL versions before 3.0.

Comment: Yeah, that's only available in legacy contexts on OS X. If you're running GL 4.x, you have a core profile and those old extensions are non-functional. The sad thing is, they still exist in the OpenGL framework and you can write code that uses them, compile and link it and only run into problems at run-time. Ideally there would be separate frameworks and glGenVertexArraysAPPLE would cause a link-time failure. I really do not know what Apple was thinking.